# Can't seem to get Mono compiler past 2.10.X? Even with Beta mono Channel

Tags: linux, centos, terminal, mono

I have been trying to update my Mono and Mono Compiler on my CentOS 7 server and i can't seem for the life of me to get it past 2.10.X. I have followed various guides, and even added the beta repo channel from Mono itself but it will not complete the mono-complete install command.

Even when i use

```
yum install mono-complete-0:4.6.0.243-0.xamarin.1.x86_64
```

It comes back with failed dependencies and broken packages it seems. It seems to still try to pull dependencies of 2.10.X instead of the updated ones? I am not sure what to do, to be honest. Here is a log of what happens when i run the above command.

[Command Log](https://ybin.me/p/37e752978eb7ef8a#FYbGl5mNShZlSYrxy7HXzJ3HDHasYSp9be/LaWvT0FY=)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up compiling mono from scratch instead, using the tar files from the download server and it worked. Funnily enough, this is embarassing but i posted a similar question **3 years** ago. I tried google searching some more, and came across my own old question (that was answered) 3 years ago on stack exchange. For anyone looking on how to just compile it from scratch instead to 4.6.0 read my old thread here.

[Previous Stack Exchange Thread With Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16070006/update-mono-via-centos)

The only thing you need to do different is update the wget links with the latest packages from monos file server. Everything else works the same!